# How to get index no. of the element of an array which matches regex in bash?

Tags: arrays, regex, bash

I have a file like this:

```
c
a
b<
d
f
```

I need to get the index no. of letter which has `<` as suffix in a bash script. I thought of reading the file into an array then matching it with the regex `.<$`. But how do I get the index no. of that element which matches this regex?

I need the index no. because I want to modify this file to get the letter which is pointed to,  move the `<` to the next line, and if it is at the last line, shuffle the order of the lines and place `<` after the first line.

Comment: Is index no same as `line no`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `awk '/<$/ { print NR; }' <your-file>`

Answer (score 1):

Grep could be used also:

```
 grep  -n  \< infile
```

Then:

```
grep  -n  \< infile|cut -d : -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So I build the source file,

```
$ cat file

c
a
b<
d
f<
```

with below awk, it will move the `<` to next line, but if it is last line, `<` will be moved to fist line.

```
awk '{ if (/</) a[NR]
       sub(/</,"")
       b[NR]=$0 }
END{ for (i in a)
       { if (i==NR) { b[1]=b[1] "<" }
         else{ b[i+1]=b[i+1] "<"}
        }
     for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print b[i]
    }' file

c<
a
b
d<
f
```

Comment: it shouldn't prefix `<` but suffix it just like before. And there won't be more than one `<` at a time. I don't speak `awk` yet so i can't really understand or modify your code. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: No problem. Since you put bash in tag, awk works fine with bash. I have edited the code, and put `<` in next line with same position (with shuffle as well). Can you try now?